# Flask/Python: Error Handlers for User Defined Exceptions

Tags: python, flask, exception

I have a simple web application made using Flask/Python. I have a user-defined exception that I am using to try and catch exceptions in my code. However, I want to show a custom error page for my user-defined exception. In Flask, I read that you have to use the `@errorhandler` decorator.

A lot of examples I read had something like this:

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
#some code
```

My question is, what goes in the parentheses specifically after `@app.errorhandler`? Do you pass in the name of the exception class you have defined? None of the examples I read online actually stated what goes between the parentheses, so I would like to know what exception to  pass in the parentheses.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler),it accepts an error code or an excpetion class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter for [`errorhandler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) is your user-defined exception. Inside the handler you can return whatever you want, which includes a template. For example:

```
from flask import render_template

class MyCustomException(Exception):
    pass

@app.errorhandler(MyCustomException)
def custom_handler(e):
    return render_template('my_custom_error_page.html')
```

In this case, whenever `MyCustomException` is raised, the app will return the html page `my_custom_error_page.html`.

You can test this forcing the exception to happen. For example:

```
@app.route('/test_exception')
def test_exception():
    raise MyCustomException('just testing :)')
```

Comment: In my route handler in my Flask application, I am using a try-except block to catch any exceptions. However, I am actually raising exceptions in my Python code that is separate from the file containing the route handler code. Even if an exception has been caught in the 'try-except' block, how would you be able to show the custom error page for that exception? Would you just raise the exception again?

Comment: If you catch the exception, it won't raise and hence the custom page won't display. If you want it to display even with a `try-except` block, simply add a this line inside your `except` block: `raise`.